# web2py SQLTABLE - How can I transpose the table?

Tags: python, web2py

I am using:

```
rows = db(db.member.membership_id==request.args[0]).select(db.member.membership_id,
    db.member.first_name,
    db.member.middle_name,
    db.member.last_name,
    db.member.birthdate,
    db.member.registration_date,
    db.member.membership_end_date)

rows.colnames = ('Membership Id', 'First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name', 
    'Birthday Date', 'Registration Date', 'Membership ending Date')
table = SQLTABLE(rows, _width="100%")
```

Now I want to transpose the table, how can I do this?

Comment: I noticed you're asking many web2py questions here. I recommend also trying the official web2py forum: http://groups.google.com/group/web2py

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rows=db(query).select(*fields).as_list()
if rows:
   table=TABLE(*[TR(TH(field),*[TD(row[field]) for row in rows]) \ 
       for field in row[0].keys()])
else:
   table="nothing to see here"
return dict(table=table)
```

Comment: This solution cause :
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment